# Projections with @Query don't work as expected when projecting to class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

When projecting to an interface everything seems to work as expected with the fields being mapped correctly. When I attempt to project onto a class (with a compatible constructor) it all works fine. When I use a `@Query` annotation I get the following exception:

`org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.HashMap<?, ?>] to type [com.example.PersonSummary]`

```
// works
PersonSummary findPersonSummaryById(long id);

// doesn't work
@Query("SELECT name AS name, age AS age FROM Person WHERE id = :id")
PersonSummary findPersonSummaryByIdQuery(@Param("id") long id);
```

See example project: https://github.com/roberthunt/spring-data-query-projection

See Spring Data Bug: [Spring Data JPA / DATAJPA-1003](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1003)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Spring Data bug has not been resolved, you should be able to work around this by using a constructor expression in the query declaration, i.e.

```
@Query("select new com.example.PersonSummary(name, age) …")
```

Comment: I think we did this to avoid having to use a native query in the first place. Is there are a reason you need to use that? You could do something like this and it should work just fine: `SELECT new com.example.domain.MyModel(lt, obj1, obj2)  FROM LeftTable lt LEFT JOIN Obj1Class obj1 ON obj1.leftRef = lt  AND <condition using right table> LEFT JOIN Obj2Class obj2 ON obj2.leftRef = lt AND <condition using right table> WHERE l.id = :id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can "force" the spring projection by creating a constructor that will accept `HashMap<?, ?>` and call a Spring bean mapper:

```
public PersonSummary(HashMap<?, ?> resultMap) {
    BeanWrapper wrapper = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(this);
    wrapper.setPropertyValues(resultMap);
}
```

Note that columns returned by DB must match the fields names of your class including proper case. So for example when using Postresql you may need to create quoted aliases with proper case, for example:

```
@Query("SELECT p.firstname as \"firstName\" from person p where ....", nativeQuery = true)
```